# Periodic Task with the use of Work Manager API in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, scheduled-tasks, android-workmanager

I have requirement to upload some data to cloud or server at/after every 3 seconds.

I thought of using **Work Manager** for this **Periodic Task** of 3 Seconds.

But while started learning the things, I got the below point for the periodic task implementation using Work Manager.

The point is :

> Note: The minimum repeat interval that can be defined is 15 minutes (same as the JobScheduler API).

So, Can't I use Work Manager for the interval of 3 Seconds?

Please guide and suggest me the best way to implement this task.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Should this upload happen whilst the app is open or in the background?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this task, the best methodology is to use a foreground service and aquire wake locks. That way, the service will always be running and you can send data every 3 seconds.
Workmanager is not suitable for your case here.

Comment: Ya please guide me. Using Work manager and with Job Scheduler the minimum duration is 15 min.

Please provide me the link for the same.